# How to Listen events in node-red - hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have deployed my business network using node-red and local composer over fabric. I would like to listen to an event in node-red. I am able to submit the transaction successfully but not able to see the notification emitted by event in the same transaction on debug console in node-red.

composer nodes are latest and Composer is 0.16v. Event url port is 7053. I have attached two images below.

Transaction Submitted - *shipmentreceived*. When the transaction processor function is executed for this transaction, event is emitted as mentioned below:

```
    var basicEvent=getFactory().newEvent('org.acme.shipping.perishable','ShipmentNotification');
    basicEvent.shipmentStatus = shipment.status;
    emit(basicEvent);
```

Model File:

```
    event ShipmentNotification{
      o String shipmentStatus
    }
```

[Node-red - Submitting and Listening event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzRRS.png)

[This could be error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5dWN.png)

Answer (score 0):

see https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/integrate-your-blockchain-with-anything-using-hyperledger-composer-and-nodered-4226676f7e54

it needs to be updated to use 'business network cards' not 'profiles' in the NodeRed node widgets / flow,  but the same principle applies where subscribing to events are concerned.